# find employees who has not taken single leave in last 1 year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables with the following columns :

```
Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER );

Leave25( EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE);
```

I want to write a query to find employees who has not taken single leave in last 1 year

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM EMPLOYEE24 E INNER JOIN ON LEAVE25 L WHERE E.EMPLOYEEID = L.EMPLOYEEID AND L.EMPLOYEEID = NULL AND STARTDATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
```

Comment: you want to calculate from current date ? or last year of current year ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR from current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's proper to use *NOT IN* for your case, as in the following :

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
  FROM EMPLOYEE24 E
  WHERE E.EMPLOYEEID NOT IN ( SELECT L2.EMPLOYEEID 
                                FROM LEAVE25 L2 
                               WHERE STARTDATE >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) );
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87f44/15)

Comment: Is that left join really needed?

Comment: But if you remove that line in your fiddle then it still gets the same results?

Comment: @LukStorms pretty cool, yes, you're right, table `EMPLOYEE24` is already enough to select `FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use a join and a subquery. You can just do it simply with:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Employee24 E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Leave25 L 
                  WHERE E.EMPLOYEEID=L.EMPLOYEEID 
                  AND (STARTDATE>=SYSDATE-INTERVAL '12' MONTH
                  OR ENDDATE>=SYSDATE-INTERVAL '12' MONTH));
```

See a [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87f44/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to find out the employees, who have not taken leaves for the last one year.

```
 SELECT E.EMPLOYEEID, E.FIRSTNAME, E.LASTNAME, MAX(L.STARTDATE), MAX(L.ENDDATE)
FROM EMPLOYEE24 E LEFT JOIN
     LEAVE25 L
     ON E.EMPLOYEEID = L.EMPLOYEEID 
GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEEID, E.FIRSTNAME, E.LASTNAME
HAVING COALESCE(MAX(L.STARTDATE),date'1900-01-01') < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12)
```

[SQLFiddle Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87f44/20)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is giving me error 
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @user2147357 . . . The query is fixed, but it is still incorrect because it requires that an employee have taken a leave at some point.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Fixed it. Thanks for your extra eye on this.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM employee24 e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM leaves25 l
    WHERE startdate > 'yearstartdate'
    AND enddate < 'yearenddate'
    WHERE l.employeeid = e.employeeid
)
```